# How to debug console message from user: [__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging, core-data

I have a user who claims that my Core Data application does not save data on his Mac. I cannot reproduce the problem, even on the exact same configuration.

All information I could get is a message my app logs to the users Console (see below). Perhaps it is related, perhaps not.

Can someone interpret this message?
If not, how would I go on to investigate the problem?

```
9/19/16 2:13:34.053 PM [MyApp][18563]: -[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7df27
9/19/16 2:13:34.053 PM [MyApp][18563]: An uncaught exception was raised
9/19/16 2:13:34.053 PM [MyApp][18563]: -[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7df27
9/19/16 2:13:34.055 PM [MyApp][18563]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e7edbd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff995614fa objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e8570ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e75e3d1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e75df58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff99071aa9 _NSCompareObject + 49
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff990e2f0f _NSSortFunctionMany + 643
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e7540a1 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 81
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e75414e __CFSimpleMergeSort + 254
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e754139 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 233
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e754139 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 233
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e753ffd CFSortIndexes + 541
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e7904c9 CFMergeSortArray + 249
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff990717d1 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 611
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff990e2c2f -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 466
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff95571a1e -[NSArrayController _sortObjects:] + 305
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff9556f2bc -[NSArrayController _arrangeObjectsWithSelectedObjects:avoidsEmptySelection:operationsMask:useBasis:] + 181
    17  [MyApp]                             0x000000010bd1671e [MyApp] + 10014
    18  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff978ff082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff9559dcf1 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9559da8b -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 336
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9559d7eb -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 114
    22  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff978ff082 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9563003c -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 131
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff9562ffaf -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 35
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff9562fe07 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 107
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff954d4575 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 708
    27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c1298e _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1231
    28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c11e18 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 404
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c27df6 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c71d2e _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 411
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c9d0f7 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 59
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c9d0a8 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 188
    33  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c9cf84 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 96
    34  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c9d92e _ZL14MenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdjPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 711
    35  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff98c9d5c8 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 460
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff954bf6c6 _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 277
    37  AppKit                              0x00007fff9533457d _DPSNextEvent + 1906
    38  AppKit                              0x00007fff95333665 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff953281c8 -[NSApplication run] + 682
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff952f145e NSApplicationMain + 1176
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff88fbf5ad start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to symbolicate the stacktrace.

Basically the sensitive information has been hidden and replaced by unique identifiers. When you, as the developer of the app, have the right tools you can translate these identifiers to useful symbols (method invocations etc.) in a process called *symbolication*.

See the following tutorial for more details and a step-by-step process:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. The problem is, this is no crash log, as the app did not crash. It is just a console message on the users Mac. Is symbolication still possible?

Comment: Yes it's also possible for console output. See the link below: [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html)